# Extract JSON info and put into object

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-core

So far I'm getting a valid response from my service with the populated JSON. My issue is how I'm supposed to parse through the JSON in order to put the `pAnn` into my object. I'm designing this for potential future use in the case that I need to assign more values from this JSON to objects. If there is an easier way to go about this, please let me know.

```
public IEnumerable<CP> GetP()
{
    string pURL, getPResult;
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

    handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        pURL = String.Concat(validurl + 5854);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(pURL);                
        HttpResponseMessage result = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress).Result;       

        if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new WebException();
        }
        else
        {
            getPResult = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }                 

        var pDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CP>>(getPResult);

        IEnumerable<CP> pResults = from cOpt in pDetails
                                                      select new CP
                                                      {
                                                          pAnn = cO.pAnn
                                                      };
        return pResults;
    }
}
```

Here is my object:

```
public class CP
{
    public string pAnn { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my JSON info I'm getting back:

```
{"data":{.... "cO":[{..... "pAnn":11111.11 .... },"errorMessages":[],"success":true}
```

I get an error at the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` line:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException occurred Message=Cannot
>   deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List because the type requires a JSON
>   array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error
>   either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the
>   deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a
>   primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or
>   List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: The linq statement doesn't seem like it does anything other than copy the original list and return that. I'd think you could remove it and just return premiumDetails.

Comment: [You're using HttpClient wrong and it's destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). I recommend you look into [Flurl.Http](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http/) or [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) which simplifies working with HTTP services and avoids the pitfalls associated with HttpClient.

Comment: Do not access `.Result` on an asynchronous call. That can cause problems. If you need the result, then call `await` on the method. Please read [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you're getting is clear. The JSON that you're getting has one single object and you're trying to deserialize it to a list `List<CoveragePremium>`. I would've told you to remove the `List<>`:

```
var premiumDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CoveragePremium>(getPremiumResult);
```

But that wouldn't work because your `CoveragePremium` class doesn't match the JSON object that you're getting. The two must match, or the deserialization will fail. If you don't want the `errorMessages` and `success`, and all you care about is the `premiumAnnual` inside `coverageOptions`, then you need to create those classes and properties at minimum:

```
public class RootObject {
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data {
    public List<CoverageOption> coverageOptions { get; set; }
    //If you want to include the other properties, uncomment the lines below:
    //public List<string> errorMessages { get; set; }
    //public bool success { get; set; }
}

public class CoverageOption {
    public decimal premiumAnnual { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can change your line to:

```
var premiumDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(getPremiumResult);
```

However, in your LINQ, you're selecting `premiumAnnual` into a `CoveragePremium` object which has its `premiumAnnual` as `string`. It is probably better to change it to `decimal` so you can use the value later as a number instead of a string:

```
public class CoveragePremium {
    public decimal premiumAnnual { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data example structure is valid json form.

```
{"data":{"coverageOptions":[{"premiumAnnual":11257.9284 }],"errorMessages":[],"success":true}}
```

I presume your sample likes above.

```
public class CoveragePremium
{
    public string premiumAnnual { get; set; }
}

public class CoverageOption
{
    public double premiumAnnual { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<CoverageOption> coverageOptions { get; set; }
    public List<string> errorMessages { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
}

public class ResultObject
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string getPremiumResult = "{\"data\":{\"coverageOptions\":[{\"premiumAnnual\":11257.9284 }],\"errorMessages\":[],\"success\":true}}";
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultObject>(getPremiumResult);

    IEnumerable<CoveragePremium> premiumResults = from value in result.data.coverageOptions
                                                      select new CoveragePremium
                                                      {
                                                          premiumAnnual = value.premiumAnnual.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                                      };

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I hope this structure is meet your needs

Comment: What is the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture supposed to reference near the end?

Comment: You don't need the `ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`)` if you change `CoveragePremium.premiumAnnual` to `double` or `decimal`. The reason it is there in the answer is to convert from `double` to `string`.

Comment: @RacilHilan says right. If you change `CoveragePremium.premiumAnnual` to double or decimal there is no needs to `ToString`, but I do not want to change your return type. Hence, I have to convert double to string. 

I configure my IDE for adding `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` automatically. Development and Production environment has not the same culture some times,so that I generally try to execute cast/convertion operation with InvariantCulture options. You can use `ToString()` also.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid errors while creating JSON classes in .NET, you can copy your JSON file and go to Visual Studio=>Edit=>Paste Special=>Paste JSON as classes. Once you do it, it will transform your JSON formatted file into classes:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public Coverageoption[] coverageOptions { get; set; }
    public object[] errorMessages { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
}

public class Coverageoption
{
    public float premiumAnnual { get; set; }
}


string yourJsonString= "{"data":{"coverageOptions":[{"premiumAnnual":11257.9284 }],"errorMessages":[],"success":true}}";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(yourJsonString);
```

Now you can access your data as:

```
var ifSuccess = result.data.success;
var coverageOption = result.data.coverageOptions[0].premiumAnnual;
```

Comment: This along with the other answers worked out perfect. Thanks for helping me out!